# Hooking thread creation/termination

Tags: windows, multithreading, hook

Is it possible to hook into thread termination on Windows? IOW, I would like to be notified if a thread inside the process (not interested in other processes and their threads) has terminated (either normally or - more important - forcefully).

Alternatively, hooking into thread creation would also do.

Rationale: I have a library that manages some information on per-thread basis (think of it as a process-wide per-thread cache for some information). When a thread is terminated I have to remove all thread-specific information from the cache. [Cache associations are implemented using thread ID which may get reused for future threads.]

There's no problem with "normal" execution order as the library user will detach the current thread from the library which will clear the state. Problems start to appear if somebody kills the thread owning cached resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to do API-level hooking of Win32 APIs like [`TerminateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I'm not seeing why you need to do this, though.  It sounds like you need to clear the thread's associated cache when the thread dies so you can re-use that slot if another thread with the same ID comes along.  Is this correct?

If so, couldn't you just clear the cache association in `DllMain` when you get the `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` event?   This is essentially your new thread notification.  At this point, you know you have a new thread, so isn't it safe to clear the existing associated cache?

The other alternative that might work is [thread-local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686749%28VS.85%29.aspx) (TLS).  You can use  Win32 APIs like [`TlsAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686801%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[`TlsSetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686818%28VS.85%29.aspx) to store thread-specific information.  You could also define a variable with [`__declspec(thread)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb%28VS.71%29.aspx) to have the compiler manage the TLS for you.  This way, each thread maintains its own cache.  The code remains the same for each thread, but the data accesses are relative to the thread.

Comment: DLL_THREAD_ATTACH would work if the library in question was implemented as a DLL but it's not. Hooking TerminateThread is a possibility, agreed.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to call
WaitForSingleObject with the HANDLE of the thread (call OpenThread using the thread id to get the HANDLE).

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Will such an event fire only on thread termination, or in other situations as well (whatever those might be)?

Answer (score 5):

If your program is in a dll, you can set up to handle the DllMain method. This is called when a thread or process starts/ends.

For example,

```
library MyDLL;

uses
   SysUtils, Windows;

procedure DllMain(reason: integer) ;
var
   dyingThreadId: Cardinal;
begin
   case reason of
     DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
     begin
          dyingThreadId := GetCurrentThreadId();
          // handle thread exit with thread id
     end;
   end;
end; 

begin
   DllProc := @DllMain;
end.
```

EDIT: The call is made in the context of the exiting thread, so you can call `GetCurrentThreadId()` to get the thread's id.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. It only gets called when a process or thread *that loads the dll* gets started or terminated. Unless every thread in the application loads this DLL, it won't get called (and if the DLL can be loaded by every thread, there are better ways to get notified when they end).

Comment: Ken, you've misunderstood. This is standard windows api - the method is called when any thread exits the process that the dll is loaded in. The dll is loaded into the process, not into the thread, so once the process loads the dll (by any thread), the dllMain is called for each exiting thread. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx in particular the DLL_THREAD_DETATCH part.

Comment: @mdma: I don't think so. Please see the first sentence of your linked topic (**emphasis mine**): "An optional entry point into a dynamic-link library (DLL). When the system starts or terminates a process or thread, it calls the entry-point function for each loaded DLL **using the first thread of the process**." Note the "first thread" in that sentence. I'm not sure how that can be more clear, but I'd be willing to admit I was wrong if you have something that demonstrates otherwise...

Comment: The documentation has changed over the years. Now it's not so clear. Although it's not expressily written, it means the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, which is called from the first thread of the process. I agree the text is unclear, but this is what it means - DLL_THREAD_DETACH is called for each thread that exits the process. Otherwise, what would be the difference between a thread detaching and the process? Please try it if you don't believe me. I've coded many "glue" dlls that use specific feature.

Comment: @mdma: I don't think this answers Mason's question (as it doesn't provide the info he's looking for, namely the ThreadID of the exiting thread). However, I'm removing my down vote because, *very* technically speaking, DLLMain *does* get called as you said (but using the first thread, as I mentioned in my comment). Therefore, *very* technically speaking, you were not wrong. Still don't think it's an answer to the question asked, though :) - just not deserving of a down vote.

Comment: @ken - I've answered the question. the call is made in the context of the exiting thread, so you can get the thread id. many implementations of thread local variables rely upon this feature.

Comment: @mdma: I see that. :) Nice work - you've reversed a down vote and made it an up vote. First time I've ever done *that*.

Comment: Thanks, although I only changed my answer slightly - the bigger change was to your understanding, Sure, misunderstandings happen. I only managed to get you to reverse the downvote because I spent the time to defend my answer. You say this is the first time you've reversed a vote - I appreciate it - but maybe there are others you've downvoted who are correct but wouldn't take the time to defend their answers. I hope in future you will only downvote when you are totally sure of something and have empirical experience to corroborate it. That way, SO will be a happier place for all.

Comment: Private flamewars aside, this really isn't an answer because I'm not running inside of a DLL.

Comment: ? 'Flamewars"? I see a discussion about an answer. Where's the flame?

Comment: +1 for the constructive discussion, and for the solution. @Mason, take mdma's hint: Quote: `I've coded many "glue" dlls that use specific feature.`. Write a tiny DLL that calls you back when a thread exits.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Win32_ThreadStopTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394496) WMI event to detect the termination of any thread in the system.

To start monitoring this event you must write a `WQL`sentence like this

```
Select * from Win32_ThreadStopTrace Within 1 Where ProcessID=PID_Of_Your_App
```

check this sample

```
uses
 Classes;

type
   TProcWmiEventThreadeCallBack = procedure(AObject: OleVariant) of object;
   TWmiEventThread    = class(TThread)
   private
     Success      : HResult;
     FSWbemLocator: OleVariant;
     FWMIService  : OleVariant;
     FEventSource : OleVariant;
     FWbemObject  : OleVariant;
     FCallBack    : TProcWmiEventThreadeCallBack;
     FWQL         : string;
     FServer      : string;
     FUser        : string;
     FPassword    : string;
     FNameSpace   : string;
     TimeoutMs    : Integer;
     procedure RunCallBack;
   public
     Constructor Create(CallBack : TProcWmiEventThreadeCallBack;const Server,User,PassWord,NameSpace,WQL:string;iTimeoutMs : Integer); overload;
     destructor Destroy; override;
     procedure Execute; override;
   end;

implementation

uses
 SysUtils,
 ComObj,
 Variants,
 ActiveX;

constructor TWmiEventThread.Create(CallBack : TProcWmiEventThreadeCallBack;const Server,User,PassWord,NameSpace,WQL:string;iTimeoutMs : Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FCallBack       := CallBack;
  FWQL            := WQL;
  FServer         := Server;
  FUser           := User;
  FPassword       := PassWord;
  FNameSpace      := NameSpace;
  TimeoutMs       := iTimeoutMs;
end;

destructor TWmiEventThread.Destroy;
begin
  FSWbemLocator:=Unassigned;
  FWMIService  :=Unassigned;
  FEventSource :=Unassigned;
  FWbemObject  :=Unassigned;
  inherited;
end;


procedure TWmiEventThread.Execute;
const
  wbemErrTimedout = $80043001;
begin
  Success := CoInitialize(nil); //CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
  try
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
    FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(FServer, FNameSpace, FUser, FPassword);
    FEventSource  := FWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery(FWQL);
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      try
       FWbemObject := FEventSource.NextEvent(TimeoutMs); //set the max time to wait (ms)
      except
       on E:EOleException do
       if EOleException(E).ErrorCode=HRESULT(wbemErrTimedout) then //Check for the timeout exception   and ignore if exist
        FWbemObject:=Null
       else
       raise;
      end;

      if FindVarData(FWbemObject)^.VType <> varNull then
        Synchronize(RunCallBack);

      FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
    end;
  finally
    case Success of
      S_OK, S_FALSE: CoUninitialize;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TWmiEventThread.RunCallBack;
begin
  FCallBack(FWbemObject);
end;
```

Now to use this thread in your app you must call it in this way

```
WmiThread:=TWmiEventThread.Create(
  Log,
  '.',
  '',
  '',
  'root\cimv2',
  Format('Select * from Win32_ThreadStopTrace Within 1 Where ProcessID=%d',[GetCurrentProcessId]),1);
```

and in the callback function

```
procedure TForm1.Log(AObject: OleVariant);
begin        
    { 
      The OleVariant parameter has these properties
      uint32 ProcessID;
      uint8  SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR[];
      uint32 ThreadID;
      uint64 TIME_CREATED;         
    }
    //do your stuff here
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Thread %s terminated ',[AObject.ThreadID]));
end;
```

Comment: +1 for yet an other WMI answer from RRUZ. Is WMI a reasonable solution in this case? Isn't the overhead too grate for such low level work? Note: I'm only going by the name, Windows Management Instrumentation, and it doesn't sound like something to be used for freeing thread variables for example.

Comment: @Cosmin, I know which is not very common use a com object to low level tasks, like monitoring threads and process. in another hand the `WMI` mainly is know by retrieving system information like hardware installed  and thinks like that, but this is only a small part of his power. personally I was wrote many applications to monitor remote systems successfully using the WMI. with the `WMI` you can detect the start of threads, process, hardware failures, new hardware connected or disconnected, etc. in summary as answer to you question `Is WMI a reasonable solution in this case?` , Yes it is.

Answer (score 3):

```
program ThreadExitHook;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  madCodeHook;

type
  TLdrShutdownThread = procedure; stdcall;

var
  LdrShutdownThreadNext : TLdrShutdownThread;

procedure LdrShutdownThreadCallback; stdcall;
begin
  WriteLn('Thread terminating:', GetCurrentThreadId);
  LdrShutdownThreadNext;
end;

begin
  HookAPI('ntdll.dll', 'LdrShutdownThread', @LdrShutdownThreadCallback, @LdrShutdownThreadNext);

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin
    WriteLn('Hello from Thread');
    Sleep(1000);
  end).Start;

  ReadLn;

  UnhookAPI(@LdrShutdownThreadNext);
end.
```

Here is a version that does not depend on any external library:

```
program Project7;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  Classes;

{==============================================================================}
function IsWin9x: Boolean;
asm
  MOV     EAX, FS:[030H]
  TEST    EAX, EAX
  SETS    AL
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function CalcJump(Src, Dest: DWORD): DWORD;
begin
  if (Dest < Src) then begin
    Result := Src - Dest;
    Result := $FFFFFFFF - Result;
    Result := Result - 4;
  end else begin
    Result := Dest - Src;
    Result := Result - 5;
  end;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function OpCodeLength(Address: DWORD): DWORD; cdecl; assembler;
const
  O_UNIQUE = 0;
  O_PREFIX = 1;
  O_IMM8 = 2;
  O_IMM16 = 3;
  O_IMM24 = 4;
  O_IMM32 = 5;
  O_IMM48 = 6;
  O_MODRM = 7;
  O_MODRM8 = 8;
  O_MODRM32 = 9;
  O_EXTENDED = 10;
  O_WEIRD = 11;
  O_ERROR = 12;
  asm
    pushad
    cld
    xor edx, edx
    mov esi, Address
    mov ebp, esp
    push    1097F71Ch
    push    0F71C6780h
    push    17389718h
    push    101CB718h
    push    17302C17h
    push    18173017h
    push    0F715F547h
    push    4C103748h
    push    272CE7F7h
    push    0F7AC6087h
    push    1C121C52h
    push    7C10871Ch
    push    201C701Ch
    push    4767602Bh
    push    20211011h
    push    40121625h
    push    82872022h
    push    47201220h
    push    13101419h
    push    18271013h
    push    28858260h
    push    15124045h
    push    5016A0C7h
    push    28191812h
    push    0F2401812h
    push    19154127h
    push    50F0F011h
    mov ecx, 15124710h
    push    ecx
    push    11151247h
    push    10111512h
    push    47101115h
    mov eax, 12472015h
    push    eax
    push    eax
    push    12471A10h
    add cl, 10h
    push    ecx
    sub cl, 20h
    push    ecx
    xor ecx, ecx
    dec ecx
  @@ps:
    inc  ecx
    mov  edi, esp
  @@go:
    lodsb
    mov  bh, al
  @@ft:
    mov  ah, [edi]
    inc  edi
    shr  ah, 4
    sub  al, ah
    jnc  @@ft
    mov al, [edi-1]
    and al, 0Fh
    cmp  al, O_ERROR
    jnz  @@i7
    pop edx
    not edx
  @@i7:
    inc edx
    cmp al, O_UNIQUE
    jz  @@t_exit
    cmp al, O_PREFIX
    jz  @@ps
    add  edi, 51h
    cmp  al, O_EXTENDED
    jz   @@go
    mov edi, [ebp+((1+8)*4)+4]
  @@i6:
    inc  edx
    cmp  al, O_IMM8
    jz   @@t_exit
    cmp  al, O_MODRM
    jz   @@t_modrm
    cmp  al, O_WEIRD
    jz   @@t_weird
  @@i5:
    inc  edx
    cmp  al, O_IMM16
    jz   @@t_exit
    cmp  al, O_MODRM8
    jz   @@t_modrm
  @@i4:
    inc  edx
    cmp  al, O_IMM24
    jz   @@t_exit
  @@i3:
    inc  edx
  @@i2:
    inc  edx
    pushad
    mov  al, 66h
    repnz scasb
    popad
    jnz  @@c32
  @@d2:
    dec  edx
    dec  edx
  @@c32:
    cmp  al, O_MODRM32
    jz   @@t_modrm
    sub  al, O_IMM32
    jz   @@t_imm32
  @@i1:
    inc  edx
  @@t_exit:
    jmp @@ASMEnded
  @@t_modrm:
    lodsb
    mov  ah, al
    shr  al, 7
    jb   @@prmk
    jz   @@prm
    add  dl, 4
    pushad
    mov  al, 67h
    repnz scasb
    popad
    jnz  @@prm
  @@d3:  sub  dl, 3
    dec  al
  @@prmk:jnz  @@t_exit
    inc  edx
    inc  eax
  @@prm:
    and  ah, 00000111b
    pushad
    mov  al, 67h
    repnz scasb
    popad
    jz   @@prm67chk
    cmp  ah, 04h
    jz   @@prmsib
    cmp  ah, 05h
    jnz  @@t_exit
  @@prm5chk:
    dec  al
    jz   @@t_exit
  @@i42: add  dl, 4
    jmp  @@t_exit
  @@prm67chk:
    cmp  ax, 0600h
    jnz  @@t_exit
    inc  edx
    jmp  @@i1
  @@prmsib:
    cmp  al, 00h
    jnz  @@i1
    lodsb
    and  al, 00000111b
    sub  al, 05h
    jnz  @@i1
    inc  edx
    jmp  @@i42
  @@t_weird:
    test byte ptr [esi], 00111000b
    jnz  @@t_modrm
    mov  al, O_MODRM8
    shr  bh, 1
    adc  al, 0
    jmp  @@i5
  @@t_imm32:
    sub  bh, 0A0h
    cmp  bh, 04h
    jae  @@d2
    pushad
    mov  al, 67h
    repnz scasb
    popad
    jnz  @@chk66t
  @@d4:  dec  edx
    dec  edx
  @@chk66t:
    pushad
    mov  al, 66h
    repnz scasb
    popad
    jz   @@i1
    jnz  @@d2
  @@ASMEnded:
    mov esp, ebp
    mov [result+(9*4)], edx
    popad
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function ApiHook(ModName, ApiName: PChar; FuncAddr, HookedApi: Pointer; var MainApi: Pointer): Boolean;
var
  dwCount, Cnt, i, jmp: DWORD;
  P: Pointer;
  hMod, OldP, TMP: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := False;
  if IsWin9x then
    Exit;
  P := FuncAddr;
  if P = nil then begin
    hMod := GetModuleHandle(ModName);
    if hMod = 0 then
      hMod := LoadLibrary(ModName);
    P := GetProcAddress(hMod, ApiName);
  end;
  if (P = nil) or (HookedApi = nil) then
    Exit;
  if not VirtualProtect(P, $40, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @OldP) then
    Exit;
  if ((Byte(P^) = $68) and (DWORD(Pointer(DWORD(P) + 1)^) = DWORD(HookedApi))) then
    Exit;
  MainApi := VirtualAlloc(nil, $1000, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  if MainApi = nil then
    Exit;
  Cnt := 0;
  for dwCount := 0 to $3F do begin
    Inc(Cnt, OpCodeLength(DWORD(P) + Cnt));
    for i := 0 to Cnt - 1 do
      PByte(MainApi)[i] := PByte(P)[i];
    if Cnt > 5 then
      Break;
  end;
  PByte(MainApi)[Cnt] := $68;
  DWORD(Pointer(DWORD(MainApi) + Cnt + 1)^) := DWORD(P) + Cnt;
  PByte(MainApi)[Cnt + 5] := $C3;
  PByte(MainApi)[Cnt + 6] := $99;
  if (OpCodeLength(DWORD(MainApi)) = 5) and
    ((Byte(MainApi^) = $E8) or (Byte(MainApi^) = $E9)) then
  begin
    jmp := DWORD(P) + DWORD(Pointer(DWORD(MainApi) + 1)^) + 5;
    DWORD(Pointer(DWORD(MainApi) + 1)^) := CalcJump(DWORD(MainApi), jmp);
  end;
  PByte(P)[0] := $68;
  DWORD(Pointer(DWORD(P) + 1)^) := DWORD(HookedApi);
  PByte(P)[5] := $C3;
  VirtualProtect(P, $40, OldP, @TMP);
  Result := True;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function ApiUnHook(ModName, ApiName: PChar; FuncAddr, HookedApi: Pointer; var MainApi: Pointer): Boolean;
var
  dwCount, Cnt, i, jmp: DWORD;
  P: Pointer;
  hMod, OldP, TMP: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := False;
  if IsWin9x then
    Exit;
  P := FuncAddr;
  if P = nil then begin
    hMod := GetModuleHandle(ModName);
    P := GetProcAddress(hMod, ApiName);
  end;
  if (P = nil) or (MainApi = nil) or (HookedApi = nil) then
    Exit;
  if not VirtualProtect(P, $40, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @OldP) then
    Exit;
  if ((Byte(P^) <> $68) or (DWORD(Pointer(DWORD(P) + 1)^) <> DWORD(HookedApi))) then
    Exit;
  Cnt := 0;
  for dwCount := 0 to $3F do begin
    Inc(Cnt, OpCodeLength(DWORD(MainApi) + Cnt));
    if (Byte(Pointer(DWORD(MainApi) + Cnt)^) = $C3) and
      (Byte(Pointer(DWORD(MainApi) + Cnt + 1)^) = $99) then
      Break;
    for i := 0 to Cnt - 1 do
      PByte(P)[i] := PByte(MainApi)[i];
  end;
  if (OpCodeLength(DWORD(P)) = 5) and ((Byte(P^) = $E8) or (byte(P^) = $E9)) then begin
    jmp := DWORD(MainApi) + DWORD(Pointer(DWORD(MainApi) + 1)^) + 5;
    DWORD(Pointer(DWORD(P) + 1)^) := CalcJump(DWORD(P), jmp);
  end;
  VirtualProtect(P, $40, OldP, @TMP);
  VirtualFree(MainApi, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
  Result := True;
end;
{==============================================================================}

type
  TLdrShutdownThread = procedure; stdcall;

var
  LdrShutdownThreadNext : TLdrShutdownThread;

procedure LdrShutdownThreadCallback; stdcall;
begin
  WriteLn('Thread terminating:', GetCurrentThreadId);
  LdrShutdownThreadNext;
end;

begin
  ApiHook('ntdll.dll', 'LdrShutdownThread', nil, @LdrShutdownThreadCallback, @LdrShutdownThreadNext);

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin
    WriteLn('Hello from Thread');
    Sleep(1000);
    WriteLn('Waking up');
  end).Start;

  ReadLn;

  ApiUnHook('ntdll.dll', 'LdrShutdownThread', nil, @LdrShutdownThreadCallback, @LdrShutdownThreadNext);

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin
    WriteLn('Hello from Thread');
    Sleep(1000);
    WriteLn('Waking up');
  end).Start;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Looks very nice.  Any way to do it without the proprietary library?

Comment: Yes, it's slightly more complicated, but doable. Basically you need to overwrite the first couple of bytes of LdrShutdownThread with a jump instruction to your own code, then do whatever you want to do and finally do whatever the instructions you overwrote did and jump back into the original LdrShutdownThread after the jump instruction. The problem is that you can't just cut any instructions in half, so you need to disassemble the original code of LdrShutdownThread to make sure that you copy a number of complete instructions. It starts the same way on all OS versions this gets easier...

Comment: a quick search finds this: https://sites.google.com/site/delphibasics/home/delphibasicssnippets/magicapihook after a quick glance at the code, this is going to do more than what you need (it's written to be able to inject dll's and hook api's in other processes) so you should be able to extract the minimum amount of code for it that you need to just hook the api in your own process.

Comment: Well, seems Jeff Atwood himself has merged Mason's question with gabr's on. A step that I have to say I strongly disagree on because the two questions are really not the same at all.

Comment: @ThorstenEngler Is it possible to hook `RtlUserThreadStart, BaseThreadInitThunk`? For starting, initialization?

Answer (score 1):

Chris' mention of DLL_THREAD_ATTACH gave me an idea ...

Basically, associating cache with thread ID is a bad thing. I have to rework my library so that a thread will initially establish some kind of handle and then manage associations using this handle.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you really want to badly enough, you could use the debugging API (e.g., `WaitForDebugEvent`, `ContinueDebugEvent`), . You'll get an EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT when a thread exits.

I can't say that's exactly a straightforward or clean way to do it, but if you can't come up with anything else, it's probably better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Boost provides [`boost::this_thread::at_thread_exit()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.atthreadexit) which allows you to provide arbitrary code to run when the current thread exits. If you call this on each thread then when it exits normally the code will be run. If a thread is terminated forcibly with `TerminateThread` then no more code is run on that thread, so the `at_thread_exit` functions are not called. The only way to handle such cases would be to hook `TerminateThread`, though this won't necessarily handle the case that another process terminates your threads.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to **reliably** do this is in a DLL that hooks DLL_THREAD_ATTACH and DLL_THREAD_DETACH.  See previous discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628148/get-notifications-of-new-threads-deleted-threads-under-windows).