# threading higher priority for a not known in advance thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I create about 5000 background workers that do intensive work in a console app. I'm also using an external library that instantiates an object, say ObjectX. At some point, say t0, ObjectX tries to obtain a thread from an os thread pool and start it, but I have no control on how it obtains this thread. Things work fine for 100 background workers. For 1000 background workers it takes about 10 minutes after t0 for ObjectX to obtain and start a thread.

1. Is there a way to set, in advance, a high priority for any threads that will be started in the future by an object?
2. As I think the answer to 1 is "no", is there a way to limit the priority of the background workers so as to somehow favor everything else? Even though I only want to 'favor' ObjectX.

The goal would be to always have available resources to run the thread launched by ObjectX, no matter how overloaded the machine is.

I'm using C# and the .Net fr 3.5, on a Windows 64bit machine.

Comment: Why is it important that ObjectX gets its thread from the pool?

Comment: 5000 background workers... madness...

Comment: I am well aware of that, still want to see an upper limit of this. If it can be done.

Comment: You can obtain ObjectX thread handle, and use SetThreadPriority to boost it. But your problem is 5000 workers...

Comment: It's not important, it's what it does according to the library documentation.

Comment: @user2161465 more workers != more work done. Stick with a reasonable number of workers, say.. 10? (an upper limit of N of cores * 2 is a good rule of thumb)

Comment: Ok, but in theory could you to this, could you create all the BWs such that, no matter what, you always have CPU time available, so that a new Thread from the TP can be created and started without any probems / waiting time?

Comment: @user2161465 You'd need to create them but not actually run them.  However that wouldn't be productive.  You'll do *much* better just creating a handful of BGWs and having a queue of work to do that each worker grabs items from whenever it's free.  This is the producer/consumer model, and it's very common in multithreaded programming.  Don't create a BGW for each single unit of work when you have that much work to do.  Your CPU will spend all of it's time switching between threads and not actually doing productive work.

Comment: @user2161465 Each Worker thread will consume overhead to be created, started, and switched to during runtime.  When you have 5K workers, that's a crap ton of overhead that your processor has to deal with and is likely hardly doing any work other than managing them all.  In producer Consumer, you could spin up roughly the same number of workers as you have logical CPUs (physical/hyperthread) and then post work items to them.  In this scenario when you need your ObjectX thread to take priority it should respond within at most 100ms (probably less depending on your hardware).

Answer (score 3):

The way threads work is that they are given processor time by the OS.  When this happens this is called a context switch.  A context switch takes about 2000-8000 cycles (i.e. depending on processor 2000-8000 instructions).  If the OS has many CPUs or cores, it may not need to take the CPU away from one thread and give it to another--avoiding a context switch.  There can only be one thread per CPU running at a time, when you have more threads that need CPU than CPUs then you're forcing a context switch.  Context switches are performed no faster than the system quantum (every 20ms for client and 120ms for server).

If you have 5000 background workers you effectively have 5000 threads.  Each of those threads is potentially vying for CPU time.  On a client version of windows, that means 250,000 context switches per second.  i.e. 500,000,000 to 2,000,000,000 cycles per second are devoted **simply to switching between threads**.  (i.e. over and above the work your threads are performing) *if it could even process that many context switches per second*.

The recommended practice is to only have one CPU-bound thread per processor.  A CPU-bound thread is one that spends very little time "waiting".  The UI thread is not a CPU-bound thread.  If your background workers are spending a lot of time waiting for locks, then they may not be CPU-bound either--but, in general, background worker threads are CPU-bound. (otherwise, what would be the point of using a background worker?).

Also, the OS spends a lot of time figuring out what thread needs to get the CPU next.  When you start changing thread priorities you interfere with that and most of the time end up making your entire system slower (not just your application) rather than faster.

## Update:

On a related not, it takes about 200,000 cycles to create a new thread and about 100,000 cycles to destroy a thread.

### Update 2:

If the impetus of the question isn't simply "If it can be done" but to be able to scale workload, then as @JoshW/@Servy mention, using something like the Producer/Consumer Pattern would allow for scalability that could facilitate horizontal scaling to multiple computers/nodes via a queue or a service bus.  Simple starting up an in ordinate amount of threads is not scalable beyond the # of CPUs.  If what you truly want is an architecture that can scaled out because "available resources...how overloaded the machine is" is simply impossible.

Comment: +1 Good explanation on why using so many threads is so expensive (and not just useless). I would only add that even in the case of non CPU-bound programs (like I/O bound ones), going much further than 1 thread per CPU does more harm than good (in that case, thread pools and relate techniques (I/O completion ports or async programming) will come to the rescue, bringing thread count down to reasonable values

Comment: @demo80 by "wait" I mean the thread is explicitly relinquishing time back to the OS via a `Wait` method (Monitor.Enter, WaitHandle.WaitX, etc.).  I wouldn't consider something like `Stream.Read` to be "waiting" (i.e. "waiting" for IO to complete) even though it's not really hogging the CPU...  But, yes, async IO should be used whenever possible.  Added detail about thread creation/destruction costs.

Comment: Excellent answer, +1 from me.  The OP should definitely be looking into changing over to the Producer-Consumer pattern rather than just spooling up a few thousand workers.

Comment: @Peter yes, of course they are somehow different (even if in the kernel the fate of the thread is more or less the same, the threads will be moved from the ready queue); still, your point applies (to a lesser degree) to this kind of wait too: threads are expensive resources, and having too many is simply bad!

Comment: @JoshW yes, a producer/consumer pattern would be a better choice for this.  It would facilitate horizontal scaling to multiple computers by way of a queue or a message bus.

Comment: '250,000 context switches per second' and 'Context switches are performed no faster than the system quantum (every 20ms for client and 120ms for server' are mutually exclusive statements.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I was expecting people to infer that; but, I've added some detail to the answer to make that explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this is a bad idea, however... given the comments you have made on other answers and your request that "No matter how many background workers are create that ObjectX runs as soon as possible"... You could conceivably force your background workers to block using a ManualResetEvent.

For example at the top of your worker code you could block on a Manual reset event with the WaitOne method.  This manual reset could be static or passed as an input parameter and wherever your ObjectX gets instantiated/called or whatever, you call the .Reset method on your ManualResetEvent.  This would block all your workers at the WaitOne line. Next at the bottom of the code that runs ObjectX, call the ManualResetEvent.Set() method and that will unblock the workers.

Note this is NOT an efficient way to manage your threads, but if you "just have to make it work" and have time later to improve it... I suppose it's one possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

> The goal would be to always have available resources to run the thread launched by ObjectX, no matter how overloaded the machine is.

Then thread priorities might not be the right tool.. [Remember, thread priorities are evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/thread-priorities-are-evil.html)

In general, windows is not a real-time OS; especially, win32 does not even attempt to be soft real-time (IIRC, the NT kernel tried, at some point, to have at least support for soft real time subsystems, but I may be wrong). So there is no guarantee about available resources, or timing.

Also, are you worried about other threads in the system? Those threads are out of your control (what if the other threads are already at the system max priority?).
If you are worried about threads in your app... you can control and throttle them, using less threads/workers to do more work (batching work in bigger units, and submitting it to a worker, for example, or by using TPL or other tools that will handle and throttle thread usage for you)

That said, you could intercept when a thread is created (look for example this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802316/863564) see if it was created for ObjectX (for example, checking its name) and use SetThreadPriority to boost it.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, not does it help the OP solve his problem.  If he shouldn't use thread priorities then what *should* he do to solve his problem?

Comment: @Servy, I added some details to my answer. He cannot solve it, windows is not a real time system. There are no guarantees on the availability of resources

Comment: You can solve the problem easily enough by just not creating 5000 threads and instead only having a dozen or so at most.  We don't know enough about what he's doing to show how that can be done, but that's almost assuredly the path he needs to go down.

Comment: I'm worried just about threads in my process. But even if I wanted to, I can't set the priority for a thread that doesn't exist yet. That;s why I thought I could allocate a limited amount of resources for the BGs I do create.

Comment: `You can solve the problem easily enough` true, but he clarified in an edit (after I pointed out that 5k threads are ... madness :), that was my first solution to the question as well) that the 5000 threads are only an example for an overloaded system (see my quote). `no matter how overloaded the machine is` include factors out of control, so there is no general solution

Comment: @user2161465 you should clarify that in your question then, it is very different from a generally overloaded machine...

Comment: my mistake, by "no matter how overloaded the machine is" i meant no matter how many BGs i start in my process, not threads from external processes.