# When exactly does a non main GUI thread exit in Windows?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, user-interface

Say the main window of a GUI application creates a helper UI thread and the application closes. When and where will the application get a chance to clean up the thread resources? I know that the system automatically clears the resources but that doesn't help application specific resources like files etc.

As a test I had written `MessageBox()` in the destructors of window objects but they are not called from within the helper threads on closing the application.

It seems the systems simply shuts down the threads, may be via internal `TerminateThread` or some such call. Is there a way to know when exactly a thread with UI terminates and trap it?

I am using Win32 API not MFC etc.

Pseudocode

```
OnCreateHelperUI() // called from WndProc under appropriate message
  CreateThread(...,UIThread,...)
  return

UIThread()
  Some auto objects on stack
  Some dynamic objects on heap
  CreateWindow()
  while(GetMessage()){}
  delete heap objects
  return 0
```

The destructors of auto and heap objects aren't called.

FYI, waiting on the thread handle doesn't help. It simply lets the threads stick around forcing the user to close them individually. `CloseHandle()` will lead back to square one.

Comment: If you have "Window" classes when are the destructors called?  Did you dynamically allocate them?  Did you call `delete`?

Comment: This is specific to C and C++, returning from main() forcefully terminates the process, regardless of how many threads are still active.  If you need cleanup then you need to make sure that this is done before main() returns.

Comment: @hans I suppose you mean its specific to Windows system as I guess same would happen if written in other langs too, or am I wrong?

Comment: @chad see the pseudocode

Comment: It looks like your main thread is terminating before the message loop is finished.  You should ensure that you signal the UI thread appropriately before allowing the main thread to finish.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hooking thread creation/termination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802244/hooking-thread-creation-termination)

Comment: @ssg not quite. The question seems similar but answers didn't help. Also my problem is specifically UI thread which isn't in DLL.

Comment: @Dirt `TerminateThread` API function is in a DLL.

Comment: @ssg of course, every API function is ultimately in some dll but that is not what I meant. The "related post" didn't help is what I am saying.

Comment: @Dirt could you add why it didn't help to the question, so others know that too?

Comment: @ssg Like I said, every reply there is for a dll scenario (although the op didn't seem to need that). Then there is alternatives about thread local storage which isn't again what I (and probably the OP there) want. Further, I don't want any third party "low level" black box library as suggested. I'd rather take a solution that solves my problem I have described either by explaining how it can be done or tells me why it can't be done at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread closes when the thread function returns.  The OS cannot do that for you, you must design it in. One good way is to have your main thread WM_CLOSE handler send a signal or message to the secondary thread. The secondary thread cleanly cleans up and returns (running destructors). While this is happening the main thread should be waiting on the thread handle, so it does not shut the app down until the secondary thread has shut down.

Comment: Well, I suppose there is no way other than this. A bit tedious with all the bookkeeping but no choice then!. Thanks.