# ASP.NET threadpool thread exit callback

Tags: asp.net, threadpool

Can I hook a method to ASP.NET threadpool thread exit ?

Would like to clean up resources after each thread is terminated.

IIS8.0 and above.
Windows 2012R2 and above.

Comment: this might be a good read [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304691/why-are-iis-threads-so-precious-as-compared-to-regular-clr-threads)

Comment: potentially need to hook into Windows C++ api, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802244/hooking-thread-creation-termination
haven't found any clue how to do this from Managed code